# How to run a Command Line PHP Script on Heroku App

Tags: php, heroku, command-line, command-line-interface, heroku-toolbelt

I have PHP apps deployed on Heroku.  How can I run a Command Line PHP Script on an app even though I don't have command line access or terminal access to the server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*( this assumes that you already have an existing PHP app deployed to Heroku )*

1) Install Heroku's Command Line Tool "[Heroku Toolbelt](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command-line)" in your local dev environment.

2) Then run this in your local terminal window:

PHP Internal Commands:

```
heroku run php --version
```

Your PHP Scripts:

```
sudo heroku run php path/to/file.php
```

( may not need to use sudo - taken from an example - I don't use sudo )

**How to run the command on a specific App.**
I have several apps running on Heroku and I usually add -a :

```
heroku run php path/to/file.php -a <app name>
```

A Default App can be set to avoid having to specify the app every time:

```
heroku git:remote -a <app name>
```